# States of $^{18}$O using nuclear shell model

Tags: nuclear-physics, isospin-symmetry

Using the nuclear shell model it can be proved that in the external shell $1d_{5/2}$ of $^{18}$O there are two neutrons. Thus, by composition of angular momentum, the possible states of the nucleus are:
$I^P$ = $0^+$ , $1^+$, $2^+$, $3^+$, $4^+$, $5^+$.

During the lecture my professor said that experimentally we can find only the states $0^+$ , $2^+$, $4^+$ and this lack can be explained through a reasoning based on isospin.

Why the states $1^+$, $3^+$, $5^+$ are prohibited?

Comment: See the answer here and links therein: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/98089/ground-state-assignment-for-nuclear-shell-model?rq=1

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ground State Assignment for nuclear shell model](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/98089/ground-state-assignment-for-nuclear-shell-model)

Comment: I have seen your answer, but I'm not asking why $0^+$ is the ground state but the reason why even state are prohibited. The pairing interaction can be the answer but I need to understand the reason and why the isospin is concerned.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You (your professor) have selected a case, where $^{16}O$ is magic nucleus and it works as a core for the games of orbitals above and it is much easier to put strong statements like *it can be proved that in the external shell $1d_{5/2}$ there are two nucleons in $^{18}O$*. We could start a discussion here...

Neverthless:  you cannot find $5^+$, it would be against Pauli principle (same projections *m=+5/2*). Wouldnt it?

More generally, for identical nucleons, the isospin projection $T_z = t_z(1) + t_z(2) = 1$ and hence total isospin is $T=1$. This is a **symetric** wavefunction (look at the *deuteron* and *pp* and *nn* cases). This implies (from Pauli principle), that the space-spin part must be **antisymetric** ....

$\Psi(j^2JM) = N \sum_{m,m'}{ (jmjm'|jjJM) [\phi_1(m)\phi_2(m')- \phi_1(m')\phi_2(m)]}$

can be rewritten as

$\Psi(j^2JM) = N \sum_{m,m'}{ (jmjm'|jjJM) - (jm'jm|jjJM) )\ \phi_1(m)\phi_2(m')}$

and for these two Clebsh -Gordan coefficients there is a rule

$\Psi(j^2JM) = N [1-(-1)^{2j-J}]  \sum_{m,m'}{ (jmjm'|jjJM) \  \phi_1(m)\phi_2(m')}$

In your case $2j=5$ is odd, so $J$ must be even, else the right side vanishes. And here you have the total angular momentum possible from $J=0,...(2j-1)$. With pure isospin $T=1$ as a gift. The $p-n$ interaction can have both isospins, which ends up with some mixing when $j_p \ne j_n$.

*Check the Casten's book (I forgot the title, but it is quite famous).*

Comment: I'm not very practical with Clebsh-Gordan coefficient (I'm learning those right now). Did the equation 
$\Psi(j^2JM) = N \sum_{m,m'}{ (jmjm'|jjJM) [\phi_1(m)\phi_2(m')- \phi_1(m')\phi_2(m)]}$ came out just because of the antisymetrization of the space-spin wavefunction?
I've always seen the CB coefficient used like:
$\Psi = \sum_{m,m'} (jmjm'|JM) \phi_1(m)\phi_2(m')$

Comment: Nobody likes C-G coefficients. Yes, you are right.  Your last equation is nice, but my one obeys the Pauli principle - put $m=m'$.